# How to check in SQL a condition for several rows with same operation? (see details)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having an uncommon situation here.

I have the following data

```
Column A  Column B
--------  --------
9999      A
9999      A    
9999      V
9999      A
9999      N

7777      A
7777      A    
7777      A
7777      A
7777      N
```

Expected Result: Only rows with 7777 will appear since there is a row with 9999 with the letter V.

I need to make the following rule. Display Column A if Column B is 'N' and different from V (<> 'V'). 
I'm having trouble with this since I have several rows with same values in column A and I only can show the value in column A if I have the value 'N' and 'V' must not exist in any row.

I hope I'm explaining this well.
Can anyone help?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Could you provide your expected output here as well?

Comment: In the example above, the value 9999 doesn't respect the rule since there is a row with V in column B.

Comment: sounds like a case statement is need here, case when b = n and v <> v  then A,
something like that

Comment: @SérgioRebelo that doesn't help show what the result is your after. Don't explain it, show it.

Comment: @Larnu I've updated the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select columnA
from t
group by columnA
having sum(case when columnB = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when columnB = 'V' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 ;
```

EDIT:

You seem to want:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and t2.item = 'N'
             ) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.item = 'V'
                 );
```

Comment: I always enjoy reading your answers Gordon.  I would not have considered this approach.

Comment: hi Gordon, thank you for your answer.
When i make this query, I only see 1 distinct value of column A since its been grouped by. I want to show the duplicate values if column B has N and don't have V in any row

Comment: @SérgioRebelo . . . That seems curious.  You could add `count(*)` to get the count.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I mean, I want to show all the operations, not the count.

In the example of my question above, the operation 9999 must not be shown since it contains a row with the number V on it.
Basically, i need to check if all rows with the same operation (9999) match with my rule (have the letter 'N' and never shows 'V' in any rows)

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think my explanation was not clear about the issue.
I've updated the description. Can you please check it? Thank you

Comment: @SérgioRebelo . . . If you want just the first column, then the first query does what you describe.  If you want the individual rows, the second does.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the details provided, this is what I believe you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.columnA
FROM myTable T1
WHERE T1.columnB='N'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM myTable T2 WHERE T2.columnB='V' AND T1.columnA=T2.columnA)
```